# Do we need to add noscript tag for all different third party scripts

Tags: javascript, html, noscript

i have installed many third party scripts on a web page.
few of them are google analytics, facebook pixel, bing tracking, google ads tracking and few more.
all of them provide a block of script and noscript codes.
for example: 
bing tracking codes

```
<script>
        (function(w,d,t,r,u){
            var f,n,i;w[u]=w[u]||[],f=function(){
                var o={ti:"5709384"};o.q=w[u],w[u]=new UET(o),w[u].push("pageLoad")},
                n=d.createElement(t),n.src=r,n.async=1,n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    var s=this.readyState;s&&s!=="loaded"&&s!=="complete"||(f(),n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=null)
                },i=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],i.parentNode.insertBefore(n,i)})(window,document,"script","//bat.bing.com/bat.js","uetq");
    </script>
    <noscript><img src="//bat.bing.com/action/0?ti=5709384&Ver=2" height="0" width="0" style="display:none; visibility: hidden;" /></noscript>
```

And facebook pixel codes

```
  <script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
    {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
    if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
    n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '756756745676'); 
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
    </script>
    <noscript>
    <img height="1" width="1" 
    src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=756756745676&ev=PageView
    &noscript=1"/>
    </noscript>
```

now my concern is do we need to add all noscript tags. would it be good if i remove all noscript tags and place a single noscript tag with a message to turn on javascript. or may be i got the wrong idea about noscript tags. Please advise.

Comment: <noscript> is just defining alternate content only displayed for browsers with scripts disabled or without support for scripts. I believe using just one noscript tag with a message would be enough..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT remove the `<noscript>` tags if they are explicitly provided to you, especially with Facebook Pixel, Google Tag Manger and the likes.

For normal users (who have scripting turned on by default), normal `<script>` tags will run and your third-party tracking tools will run as expected, thus properly contribute to your analytics.

However, for some users who have their scripting turned off, normal `<script>` tags won't run, thus your analytics will not be accurate anymore. This is where `<noscript>` come into play.

If you noticed, the `<noscript>` provided by these third-party analytics have an `<iframe>` or `<img>` with a `src` attribute along with your "app_id". With Facebook Pixel and GTM, you will also see something like "PageView" or the likes in the attribute.

Whenever the `<iframe>` or `<img>` with the `src` is loaded, a page view count is attributed to your tracking ID.

So, in the event where scripting is turned off, `<noscript>` will now function to track your web performance, making your analytics more accurate (even though some advanced tracking features is not possible).

Read the details [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide) and [here](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-tag-manager-noscript/).